# Azure VM: Auto Shutdown fails to shutdown

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

I have an Azure VM. I enabled Auto-Shutdown on the VM, then provided the time and time zone. Also I entered the notification email and web hook address. However when it doesn't work.

The VM is still running, the web hook hasn't been hit, i haven't received any email.

What am I missing here? Where and What should I investigate next?

Comment: Have you tried to turn off auto-shutdown and turn it on it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tried in my environment; everything is working successfully like below:**

- Make sure to schedule **shutdown** time more than half an hour from current time.
- Please check if you have given the settings like below:

[image]

- I received the email successfully with subject **"Alert—Auto-shutdown of virtual machine yourvm in specified minutes"** as below:

[image]

- As suggested by @[Ked Mardemootoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16046045/ked-mardemootoo) , try ***disabling and enabling the shutdown.***

**If still the issue persists**, maybe there is a backend issue in your VM. In that case I would suggest you to raise [**Azure support request**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/)